# Best Approch to define LinkedHashSet in Domain Model

Tags: java

Which will be the best Approch to define LinkedHashSet in Java Domain Model out of below two option

Option 1

```
private Set<String> myCollection;

public Set<String> getMyCollection() {
    if (myCollection == null) {
        return new LinkedHashSet<String>();
    } else {
        return myCollection;
    }

}

public void setMyCollection(Set<String> myCollection) {
    this.myCollection = myCollection;
}
```

Option 2

```
private LinkedHashSet<String> myCollection;

public LinkedHashSet<String> getMyCollection() {
    return myCollection;
}

public void setMyCollection(LinkedHashSet<String> myCollection) {
    this.myCollection = myCollection;
}
```

Comment: Actually I am confused about approach and about performance And my requirement is LinkedHashSet only not any other implementation.

Comment: There is no significant performance difference. The performance is the last thing you should worry about. What you need to worry about is correctness, robustness, maintaibability and readability. Should the set ever be null? Why name a set `myList`? Why does the first code declare it as a Set and the second one as as a LinkedHashSet? Should you accept any kind of Set, or only LinkedHashSet?

Comment: This is obviously opinion-based. And my opinion is to _never_ have a getter and/or a setter for collections. Consider the model of a person that has several phone numbers. Technically, you use a list (or maybe a set) for holding those phone numbers. But if you provide a getter, you are modelling the following fact: A person has a list that holds phone numbers. This is not what you usually want. Instead provide methods for adding and removing phone numbers that are implemented by accessing the (internal) list.

Comment: @JBNizet I want ordered unique data so LinkedHashSet only choice.

Comment: Then the setter in the first snippet is not acceptable, since it replaces myList by any kind of Set. I second @Seelenvirtuose: a setter for a collection is rarely a good idea. It breaks encapsulation. It should at least copy the elements from the passed collection to the internal one, instead of blindly using the foreign collection (which might be synchronized, or fixed size, or not serializable, etc.).

Comment: Thanks to all for nice discussion.
@JBNizet setter for collection used for JUnit testing only.

Comment: @Pushkar that's a problem per se. You shouldn't modify the public interface of a class just for JUnit tests. And there is guarantee at all that noone will ever call this public method since... it's public.

Comment: @JBNizet what if we modify set method to mutable?

Comment: Give it package (default) visibility only. Your unit test should be in the same package

Comment: A method can't be mutable. An object can be. And if it has a setter, then it already is. Not sure what you mean.

Comment: @grid actually I am working maven base project so its not possible us to put it in same package 
And thanks a lot for valuable input

Comment: @JBNizet sorry, I mean setter with immutable parameter.

Comment: You shouldn't force callers to pass immutable objects. What you should do is to make sure the invariants of your class are always respected, and that a caller doesn't have any way to break them. So, if you want to make sure the set is never null and is always a LinkedHashSet, then you should clear your set and copy all the elements from the argument to the set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a good practice, you should return empty collections, not nulls, even if they contain no elements. A good way to be safe is to instantiate them on declaration.
Secondly you should program to interfaces than implementations when possible. Unless your client code makes use of some special feature of the implementation class you should declare and return the interface type. This makes it possible to change the implementation later without breaking client code.

So your declaration may be written as :

```
private Set<String> mySet = new LinkedHashSet<String>();
```

The only reason for considering lazy initialization (inside the getter) is optimization. For example you may anticipate a very big number of instances while very few of them may need to be accessed. Otherwise the robustness vs performance factor does not pay off.

As Seelenvirtuose commented, you may also opt to provide some collection-builder code and not expose the collection itself with a getter. This is mostly the case in bidirectional associations (when the collection element object keeps a reference in the object hosting the collection). But even then client code may need access to the collection. Use the *java.util.Collections.unmodifiableSet()* method to expose a unmodified view of the collection.  (Of course in this case you should also eliminate collection setters).

Also as JB Nizet stated you should be very careful with the setters.  If you decide to add them, you have to take care of not introducing side-effects. If the passed collection is also referenced by other objects, your class may modify the sate of those objects inadvertently which causes nasty bugs, difficult to be spotted sometimes.
As you understand your approach depends on how much control you have on client code, and on the use cases your class serves. In many cases a trade-off towards simplicity is common.